# Representing this graph in Python

Tags: python, graph

What is one way to represent this graph in a Python data structure?

[Example Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97ulj.jpg)

The graph will always be a closed envelope and each vertex will contain an x and y value. There will always be 3...n vertices. No other information is needed along the paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) the code could look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import pylab

pp = np.array([
    [-400, -50000],
    [800, -50000],
    [6000, -16000],
    [6000, 30000],
    [4400, 40000],
    [-3000, 40000],
    [-6000, 12000],
    [-6000, -16000]
])

pylab.scatter(pp[:, 0], pp[:, 1])

pylab.gca().add_patch(patches.Polygon(pp, closed=True, fill=False))
pylab.grid()
pylab.show()
```

And the output would be:

[image]